# Перемещение по строкам таблицы

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Я нарисовал таблицу.

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на строку она становилась "активной" - выделялась другим цветом, например. Есть класс `.Selected`, и я хочу добавить его конкретной строке.

И ещё при нажатии клавиш вверх/вниз хочу сделать перемещение этого класса на строки вверх/вниз. Т.е. как `ListBox`. Подскажите, как такое сделать?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, возникает затруднение?

Comment: Есть ли где-то примеры кода, на jquery, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Наскоро сделал [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/6may9L1h/). Что-то в нем не понятно — спрашивайте, объясню.

(Для себя в процессе узнал про `.eq()` и `closest()` - раньше не пользовался ими.)

Answer (score 1):

вот вам событие для клика: http://api.jquery.com/click/

а вот пример для перемещения с клавиатуры: http://jsfiddle.net/QFzCY/ (взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404175/up-down-left-right-keyboard-navigation-with-jquery))

теперь только осталось сложить 2+2 ;)

Comment: Почему, когда я ставлю alert();  он врубается n количество раз? хотя кнопку я нажимаю 1 раз

Comment: Нужно смотреть код, как вариант: у вас алерт в цикле каком-нибудь поставлен.